# Iterate through a linked list in Java while filtering directly in the next() method?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I'm having some issue with a part of my homework for CS. I need to write a Linked List in Java and then only iterate the odd numbers with an Iterator. Essentially, a forEach loop must iterate only through odd numbers.

So far I only have this in my LinkedList class:

```
public class Iterator implements java.util.Iterator<Integer> {

    private Node nextNode;

    public Iterator(){
        nextNode = head_;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (nextNode != null);// && (nextNode.data_ % 2 != 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        if (!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Integer data = nextNode.data_;
        nextNode = nextNode.next_;
        return data;
    }

    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}

public Iterator iterator() {
    return new Iterator();
}
```

If I uncomment `&& (nextNode.data_ % 2 != 0);`, then only the first number ( which happens to be uneven) is printed. I've also tried to implement this in the next() method, but without success.

Please give me a tip what to try further.

//Later edit: I failed to mention that the linked list I want to filter consists of random numbers and is not sorted.

Comment: Do you start from 0 or 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should look at the official documentation for `Iterator.hasNext` and `Iterator.next`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

For `hasNext` we read

> Returns true if the **iteration** has more elements

The internal structure does not matter. So we have no choice, our implementation has to check the whole linked list till it finds either an odd element or the end of the list. Also note that a call of `hasNext` should not change your structure.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
        Node tempNode = nextNode;   // nextNode need to stay the same
        while (tempNode != null){
            if (tempNode .data_ % 2 != 0){
                return true;
            }
            tempNode = tempNode._next;
        }
        // if we are here, we found no element that is odd
        return false;
    }
```

Now the `next` method is almost the same, this time we need to advance the internal `nextNode`. If we fail to do it, the caller will always get the same element.

```
public Integer next() {
    while (nextNode != null){
            int data = nextNode.data;
            nextNode = nextNode.next_;
            if (data % 2 != 0){
                return data;
            }
    }
    //no odd element was found
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your filter should be located inside your `.next` method, not `.hasNext`. This is simple logic: you iterate through whole list, and `hasNext` has to return `true` all times except when current element is the last one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you are right, this makes sense. I just have no idea how to implement this in the `next` method.

Comment: hasNext() should return false even when there are still elements in the list, but none of the remaining elements satisfy the condition.

Comment: @Meier i dont like the idea to add filtering to iterator. Instead of that i would try to generate Stream from plain Iterator and then just `.filter` it.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This should be the way to do it if you want only odd data points. I think we were assuming you wanted odd indexes to begin with.

```
@Override
public Integer next() {
    //keep looking for an odd element as long as there is a next
    while (hasNext()) {

     //move to the next node
     nextNode = nextNode.next_;

     //check for an odd data point
     if (nextNode.data_ % 2 == 1) {

      //and return it
      return data;
     }
    }

    //no odd element was found
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it would normally work, but I failed to mention that the elements are not in order and basically random.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use nextnode.next_ twice in order to get only the odd numbers. This is because you want to skip nextnode.next_ because that would always be an even number if your current one is an odd number. Additionally, your hasnext needs to check two spaces ahead